# MVC Render PartialView from string

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to render a partial view, But the complex thing is that I need to 
Write it as String, As follows:

```
string str = "Hello {Form} Goodbye !!!";
@Html.Raw(str.Replace("{Form}", "@Html.Partial("_PartialView", Model)"))
```

now, I need the compiler to understand that @html.Partial is MVC HtmlHelper Command and not string.

Any Idea ?

Thanks,
Yaniv

Comment: the way you trying to do this is wrong. I prefer you to use simple Razor's if-else if it is condition based.

Comment: What do you mean ? @Html.Partial is not a razor command but mvc HtmlHelper, Can you give an example?

Comment: I must replace the {Form} placeHolder

Comment: This is an ugly idea. Just pass a model into your partial and use it there.

Comment: Robert, Still not answers my question, I need to replace the placeHolder with the partialView, It is more complicated than you think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use

```
@Html.Raw(string.Format("Hello {0} Goodbye !!!",Html.Partial("_PartialView", Model)))
```

or

```
@Html.Raw(string.Format(str.Replace("{Form}", "{0}"),Html.Partial("_PartialView", Model)))
```

Comment: Great answer !!

Answer (score 0):

The most possible solution to your problem is you need to make ajax call and fetch the partialview result and than replace that result in your string like.

```
<script>
    string str = "Hello Form Goodbye !!!";
    replacement();
    function replacement(){
    $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetPartialView", "Utility")',
                type: 'GET',
                data:{
                  param1 : "value1",
                  param2 : "value2",
                  param3 : "value3",
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response != null) {
                        str = str.replace('Form',response);
                    }
                },
                error: function (response) {
                }
            });
    }

</script>
```

In your controller class

```
public ActionResult GetPartialView(PartialViewModel model)
{
    return PartialView("_PartialView", model);
}
```

Comment: This may be worked, but more complicated than 'soilovecuu' ones.